# Is [-1,1]-{0} compact set?!

Tags: general-topology

Is [-1,1]-{0} compact? 
I know that [-1,1] is compact .
because:
The Heine-Borel theorem states that a subspace of (with the usual topology) is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Well, then you know what questions to ask: Is it bounded? Is it closed?

Answer (score 2):

No, because a compact set is closed and this set is not closed.

Indeed, the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ lives in $[-1,1]\setminus \{0\}$ but its limit doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Again by Heine-Borel you can see that $[-1,1] - ${0}$ $ is not compact, because its not closed.

Actually any point of a close segment $[a,b]$ is a limit point for this segment and removing the point will disorder its compactness.